# Docker compose share volume from one container to another (Windows)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I can create an empty volume and map it to multiple containers or map data from a host.
What I can't do: is to have shared data between multiple containers, where the folder `C:/inetpub/wwwroot/web/Folder` inside of the container with data should be exposed to other containers.
Is it possible to achieve using `docker-compose`?

```
services:
  web1:
    image: docker.local:5000/web:latest
    container_name: web-node1
    hostname: WebNode1
    isolation: process
    tty: true 
    volumes:
      - datavolume:C:/inetpub/wwwroot/web/Folder
    expose:
      - 80
    networks:
      - net
  web2:
    image: docker.local:5000/web:latest
    container_name: web-node2
    hostname: WebNode2
    isolation: process
    tty: true
    volumes_from:
      - web1:rw
    expose:
      - 80
    networks:
      - net
networks:
    net:
volumes:
    datavolume: {}
```

Comment: If you can avoid the shared volume, that'd be better in a couple of ways.  What you show here seems like it should work; repeating the `volumes:` in the second container is a little better than using `volumes_from:`.  Is there a specific problem you're running into?

Comment: There is no issue with `volumes_from`, the main problem is that I can't share data from a container. In case of creating a volume `datavolume` will overwrite my  existing data with empty volume. What I need to do is: attach existing data in folder `C:/inetpub/wwwroot/web/Folder` from `web1` to `web2`.

Comment: "Creating a volume will overwrite my existing data with empty volume": correct.  You can't directly mount a directory from one container to another.  If you can't avoid the file sharing then you may need to set up the "source" container to copy its data into the volume on startup, maybe with an entrypoint wrapper script.